# Total size of an index or primary key can not exceed 900 bytes

Tags: sql-server

When I try to create UK for 7 columns I get

> Total size of an index or primary key
>   can not exceed 900 bytes.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Quite simply: reduce the size of your index. No index entry in SQL Server can be more than 900 bytes - that's a fixed, hard limit. No way around it. Can you show us how you're trying to create the unique index?? What fields are involved in this unique index??

Comment: @marc_s From [the OP's previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686297/t-sql-unique-constraints-over-7-columns-by-sql-management-studio) I don't think it is the PK.

Comment: @Martin Smith: thanks for the heads-up !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The question was asked in 2010. SQL Server 2016 has increased the limit [to 1700 bytes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2016/04/26/increased-nonclustered-index-key-size-with-sql-server-2016/) for nonclustered indexes - so one option could be upgrading.

If there is still a requirement to enforce a unique constraint over the allowed limit see [this article](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1868) for some suggestions of workarounds.

- CHECKSUM (Possible collisions)
- Triggers (High Overhead and might fail under snapshot isolation)
- HASHBYTES (Less chance of collisions but still possible)

Answer (score 4):

If you are in SSMS you will get this error and will not be able to create the index.

You can however can script it out and the same index creation will only produce a warning.

> Warning! The maximum key length is 900 bytes. The index
>   'IX_Member_LoginName' has maximum length of 2000 bytes. For some
>   combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail.

script was

```
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Members_LoginName] ON [dbo].[Members] 
 (
    [LoginName] ASC 
  )
 WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE =
 OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF,
 ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 1):

Other than the obvious (changing the size of these 7 columns), there's no setting or similar. You can however enforce this by using triggers to ensure those 7 columns are unique together.